# What is correct open api description to add user to group if I want tp follow REST?

Tags: rest, http, openapi, openapi-generator

I have 2 entities:

- user
- group

Now I want to have endpoint to add user(s) to group

```
paths:
  /groups/{id}/members:
    post:
      operationId: blabla
      summary: Add user to group
      parameters:
        - name: id
          required: true
          in: path
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/ID'
```

I am quite sure about url = `/groups/{id}/members`

But am not sure about **http method**. Should it be **patch** or **put** ? If it is **post** I prefer to response with id of newly created entity but I don't create anything here.

Should I pass user id in the **url** or in the **body** ?

Answer (score -1):

put / post both ok, patch is more on modify a record.

normally user id should be in body, when you doing insert

Comment: So what is your complete suggestion ?